# Laravel Eloquent How to fetch results from array

Tags: php, laravel

I have been spending hours searching to find this.

I am very new to Laravel, ( coming from CodeIgniter ) and I am trying to do everything the Laravel way instead of using pure php/sql anywhere unless it is very necessary.

```
$role_id = Role::select('role_id')
                    ->where('type','Admin')
                    ->get();
    var_dump($role_id);
```

I am trying to fetch $role_id.

The var_dump gives me this.

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#249 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(App\Role)#252 (26) { ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["table":protected]=> string(5) "roles" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(1) { ["role_id"]=> int(99) } ["original":protected]=> array(1) { ["role_id"]=> int(99) } ["changes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } } } }
```

I expected just a mysql result row instead of this.

What I am looking for is just this `["role_id"]=> int(99)`.

I am missing a function to directly get this, and I cant find it from the docs.

`$role_id->role_id` gives me property not found.

Comment: `foreach ($role_id as $id)
{
    var_dump($id->role_id);
}` sorry if wrong but try this

Comment: @vimuth Doesnt work. Not an object to get the property.

Answer (score 1):

You have items with get method. This of the reasons cannot access role_id.

You can use first instead of get method if you want to one record.

and you can use dd() function.

```
$role_id = Role::select('role_id')
                ->where('type','Admin')
                ->first();
dd($role_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `->first()` instead of `->get()`. 
`get()` returns collection.

Comment: Returns the same thing as there is only 1 row.

Comment: $role = Role::where('type','Admin')
                      ->first();
$role_id = $role->role_id

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$role_id = Role::all(['role_id'])->where('type','Admin')->first(); or Role::where('type', 'Admin');

Instead of var_dump you can use dd($role_id) or var_dump($role_id), it dies and dumps at the same time .
```

Comment: I need to get the value of role_id from the DB. I still dont get it using what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way of doing it.

```
$response = Role::select('role_id')
                       ->where('type','Admin')
                       ->first();
        $admin_id = $response->role_id;
```